# Java HashMap KeyEvent

Tags: java, hashmap, key-bindings

Am trying to make some custom key binds. 
using a hashmap to send a command if the integer is pressed. 
problem am having is

1. its doing the command in `[]`
2. its sending the command mutiple times.

The code:

```
for (String key : CustomKeys.keySet()) {
    Integer value = CustomKeys.get(key);
    if (keyIsPressed(value)) {
        print(CustomKeys.keySet().toString());
        break; //Tried to break it so it didnt send it mutiple times. didnt work
    }
}
```

Comment: If a key is pressed. the key bering the integer in a hashmap. send the string in the hashmap. it does this. but does it mutiple times. aswell prints [] around the string

Comment: do you wanna print the key in the hash map if it is pressed ?

Comment: Sorry i pressed enter before i was done. read it now

Comment: can you show us how your hashmap looks ?

Comment: public static HashMap<String, Integer> CustomKeys = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly, you wanna print the key (String in your map)when a value(value in your map)pressed.If you use break, it would exit from the loop when its encountered.
if you wanna check for duplicate values in the map do something like this.

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> CustomKeys = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
public HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();
for (String key : CustomKeys.keySet()) {
        Integer value = CustomKeys.get(key);

         if(keyIsPressed(value)) {
           if(!hs.contains(value)) {
           hs.add(value);
            print(CustomKeys.keySet().toString());
}
 else {
sysout("duplicate");
}
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but i fixed it. it was a derp mistake it was placed with all my orther none custom keys. so it print'ed out x amount of times x bering the none custom keys amount

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have duplicate values in your hash map, whatever this is all about.

Comment: duplicate values .. :) not keys.. :)

Comment: static{
  CustomKeys.put("Yes", Keyboard.KEY_RSHIFT);
 } pretty sure its just there once

Comment: @CodersRock It is 100% certain that there is a duplicate, otherwise the behaviour you describe woudn't occur. The fact that that line of code only occurs once isn't relevant. Do you know for a fact that all the values of those symbolic constants are distinct?